# Bootstrap 3.3.7 dropdown menu not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

We populating our dropdowns from a JSON file, but for some reason, it's not working on mobile. Except for the li anchors, I'm following the guidelines from the Bootstrap 3.3.7 documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns.

I also added this, but the issue persists on mobile devices:

```
$('.dropdown-backdrop').css({display: 'none'});
```

What could be causing this? Here's my dropdown code.

```
<div class="dropdown w-100 open" id="attrib">
  <button data-device="Umbra 501" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Economy
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <li><a data-filter-dropdown="Small">Small</a></li>
    <li><a data-filter-dropdown="Medium">Medium</a></li>
    <li><a data-filter-dropdown="Large">Large</a></li>
    <li><a data-filter-dropdown="Xlarge">Xlarge</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

UPDATES
This site is AEM 6.5. Also I noticed that all the dropdowns have the same id ("attrib").

Comment: Please check have added jquery before bootstrap js

Comment: I confirmed that jQuery loads before Bootstrap.